# d3.js dynamic data reload possibly related to exit().remove()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have implemented this d3 visualization http://bl.ocks.org/4745936 , to be loaded with dynamic data instead of a .tsv

in my case, once my server passes new information to the selector, a second chart gets rendered under the first one, instead of modifying the contents of the existing graph.

I believe it has to do with this `append` method.

```
var svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

so I tried adding other `exit().remove()` methods to legend and cities variables right after they `append('g');` but my javascript console says the `exit()` method does not exist at that point.

I feel I have the completely wrong approach, how do I update an existing graph like this? Having a second and third graph get generated alongside the previous ones is not the outcome I wanted at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem with some jQuery and CSS voodoo

basically since my d3 graph adds an svg element to an existing selector (a div in my case), I was able to check for the name of this dynamically

`var svgtest = d3.select(selector+" > svg");`  getting the svg subchild element of that div. then I could use jquery to remove that element from the dom completely, and then let d3 continue running and append svg's all it wants!

```
 var svgtest = d3.select(selector+" > svg");
    if(!svgtest.empty())
    {
        $(selector+" > svg").remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're right the append method is adding a new svg element every time. To prevent the duplicate charts you need to check if the svg element exists already. So try something like this at the begining:

```
var svg = d3.select("#mycontainer > svg")
if (svg.empty())
    svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg");
...
```

As stated in the [exit() docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-exit), *This method is only defined on a selection returned by the data operator.* So make sure that you're calling exit on a selection returned from `.data(..)`.

Comment: so it checks the selector properly, but I am still having issue with the exit() method.  var legend = svg.selectAll('g')
       .data(cities)
       .enter();
     
       legend.exit().remove(); this still "returns method has no exit" in my console

Comment: @CQM if you could simplify your code and make it show the error I think it will help both of us. For example, most of the stuff in there (complex data, legends, text, etc.) are not relevant to the problem. Simplify the issue and if you don't find the problem share the fiddle and I'll take a look. The docs on exit that I linked to above are also a good resource. They show some simple examples taht might help.

Comment: I used the concept behind this answer to solve my problem, I posted the answer here though

Answer (score 1):

scott's answer is one way of ensuring that the initialization happens only once.

However, I prefer a more *d3-ic* way of handling this:

```js
var svg = d3.select(selector)
            .selectAll('svg')
            .data( [ dataFromTSV ] ); // 1 element array -> 1 svg element

// This will be empty if the `svg` element already exists.
var gEnter = svg.enter()
               .append('svg')
               .append('g');

gEnter.append( ... ); // Other elements to be appended only once like axis

svg.attr('width', ...)
   .attr('height', ...);

// Finally, working with the elements which are surely in the DOM.
var g = svg.select("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

g.selectAll(...).attr(...);
```

This approach is exemplified in [the reusable charts example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/)'s [source code](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/time-series-chart.js).

I prefer this approach because it keeps the code very declarative and *true* to the visualisation by hiding away the logic of initialisation and updates.

---

I would modify the original example: http://jsfiddle.net/8Axn7/5/ to http://jsfiddle.net/3Ztt8/

Both the legend and the graph are defined from `svgElem` with one single element of data:

```js
var svgElem = d3.select("#multiLinegraph").selectAll('svg')
            .data([cities]);

// ...

var svg = svgElem.select('g');

// ...


var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
    .data(
        function (d) { return d; },
        function (d) { return d.name; } // Object consistency 
    );

// ...


var legend = svg.selectAll('g.legend')
    .data(
        function(d) { return d; }, 
        function (d) { return d.name; } // Object consistency 
    );
```

Also, the *static* properties are set only once when the element is entered (or exited), while the update properties are set (transitioned) with each update:

```js
gEnter.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y multiLineaxis")
  .append('text')
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Requests (#)");

svg.select('g.y.multiLineaxis').transition().call(yAxis);
```

The code, in my opinion, follows the cycle of enter-update-exit cleanly.

Comment: can you show me how the chart I am using would be rewritten in a jsfiddle to accommodate this paradigm?

Comment: @musically_ut I like that 1 element array approach. nice.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ericps/8Axn7/ this version won't render in jsFiddle but it can be tidyed up here

Comment: `data` and `cities` are not defined. Can you initialize them with dummy data in the correct format at the top of the script?

Comment: @musically_ut they are defined now, but it still doesnt run in the fiddle

Comment: I think you forgot the link to the updated jsFiddle. Also, you can debug errors in javascript in jsFiddle by opening the web-console, just like on a normal webpage.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should remove old svg, after then you can add updated charts.
For that you should add only one line before you append svg.
And its working.

```
 var flag=d3.select("selector svg").remove();
```

//----your old code would be start here-------

```
var svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg")
```